# How to make a shape curved to inside

Tags: android, shapes

I have a bottom nav that had a shape corner and i want to make something above it and it should be curved to inside like this image

[image]

Comment: You can use Bottom Sheets https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

Answer (score 0):

Create Drawable which have top corners as round shape

navigation_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
                android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Replace view background with `navigation_background.xml` to make view top corners as round.

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_background"
    ... />
```

Comment: I already create the BottomNavigationView shape and it works
I want to create the shape of the card above the BottomNavigationView

Comment: you have to create navigation background as above to give padding to second overlap shaped. Then create required background for above card view. Top of bottom navigation background align with bottom of card view background.